# Forever Node.js Caching Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, forever

I keep on getting caching issues. I uploaded a newer version of my code, but Forever keeps on referring to my old code. I added the -w option when I start my program so that it'll watch for changes, but that's not working. How do you fix this?

Comment: Did you `forever stop` first?  What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, I stopped the forever with `forever stopall`. I looked at my logs to see if it's an issue with my code because I was getting a load issue with my file. When I just tried `node server.js`, it ran fine. That's all I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the problem that `forever stop` didn't work, it just wouldn't stop the node process. On a Linux machine, what helped was:

```
ps -ax | grep node --> if the server's still running, kill it
pkill node
```

Then start forever agin.

Comment: What does `ps -ax` do? I can't find it on Google. Do you mean `ps -aux`?

Comment: Ja, they seem do the same thing.. I once read somewhere (can't find that page again now) that -ax comes from BSD syntax, maybe it's a historic thing.. Good luck with forever, hope someone can help you..